# Select first table row by default

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this Angular application which displays selected table rows:

```html
<div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 432px; height: 100px;">
   <div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="370" class="ag-row ag-row-focus ag-row-even ag-row-selected ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row.">
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="371" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
         <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-tkr-c21="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-tkr-c21="" class="far fa-check-square"></i><i _ngcontent-tkr-c21="" class="far fa-square" hidden=""></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
      </div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="372" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 32px;">4</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="373" col-id="shipmentLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-focus ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 132px;">20</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="374" col-id="carrierName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 232px;"></div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="5" comp-id="375" col-id="shipmentExpectedDate" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 332px;">2021-01-28T16:20:35.987</div>
   </div>
   <div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="376" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row.">
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="377" col-id="rowCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  ">
         <mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer _nghost-tkr-c21="" class="ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-tkr-c21="" class="far fa-check-square" hidden=""></i><i _ngcontent-tkr-c21="" class="far fa-square"></i></mobileweb-checkbox-selection-renderer>
      </div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="378" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 32px;">3</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="379" col-id="shipmentLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 132px;">19</div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="380" col-id="carrierName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 232px;"></div>
      <div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="5" comp-id="381" col-id="shipmentExpectedDate" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 332px;">2021-01-28T12:36:31.057</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Full code
https://pastebin.com/GUaHHnpA

How I can always click on the first table row and select it using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Comment: have you tried nth-of-type css selector ? .ag-row:nth-of-type(1) or div[role=“row”]:nth-of-type(1) ?

Comment: No, can you show me code example please?

Comment: They already did in their comment?

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: Explain what exactly you want to achieve at the UI. Consider to show some little example at some sort of online editor like Stackblitz. Also, the tags you have putted are un-related. Remove them and put "Angular" tag for get help from Angular developers.

Comment: Note that I want to implement this using Selenium framework.

Answer (score 2):

The link that you have shared for full `HTML code`, does not have `<body> tag` in it, nonetheless it has `</body>`, so can you `re-verify` that first ?

Now, based on the HTML code above, **if the goal is to select the first table row**,  here is my suggestion/Recommendations.

You can achieve that in two ways :-

1. Use of `xpath indexing`
2. use of `Selenium - findElements()` method

**Demonstration of case 1 :**

if this **xpath**

```
//div[@role='row']
```

represent rows in the `HTML`, you would see lot of entering in DOM.

and in your case, since you wanna grab the first item, it'd be something like this  :

```
(//div[@role='row'])[1]
```

in case if you'd like to select `2nd row`, or `3rd row`, we can get it done using changing this value from above xpath :

`[1]` to `[2]` or `[3]`

in code you can use it like below  :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement firstRow = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@role='row'])[1]")));
firstRow.click();
```

****Demonstration of case 2 :****

**2.1 :**

```
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='row']"));
WebElement firstRow = allRows.get(0);
firstRow.click();
```

OR

**2.2 :**

```
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='row']"));
for (WebElement rows : allRows) {
    rows.click();
    break;
}
```

The below part is request by OP (additionally, it has nothing to do with the original question)

if you have already implemented `WebDriverEventListener`  Interface or extended `AbstractWebDriverEventListener Class`, you can make use of the below methods  :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement firstRow = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@role='row'])[1]")));
beforeClickOn(firstRow, driver);
firstRow.click();
afterClickOn(firstRow, driver);
```

and let's say this is written in `class A` then you can extends it like this  :

```
public class A extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me also how to click on the row in order to select it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov : Yes, updated the post above, do check it out and let me know if that works. All you have to do is `firstRow.click();`

Comment: Is it possible to add wait listener for the above code?

Comment: yes we can, have you already implemented `WebDriverEventListener ` interface in your project or extends this `AbstractWebDriverEventListener Class`.

Comment: no, can you show me code example, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov : You can even extends your current class like above. Do let me know if you have any more open concerns regarding this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The first row has `ag-row-first` and `ag-row-selected` classes, you can use either one. This will match 3 elements (according to the html you posted in the link), so you can combine it with a parent element that doesn't have `ag-hidden` class

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:not(.ag-hidden) > .ag-row-first"));
```

In general, `findElement` will return the first matching element in the DOM, so

```
driver.findElement(By.className(".ag-row-selected"));
```

Or its equivalent

```
driver.findElements(By.className(".ag-row-selected")).get(0);
```

Should have worked if the row was really the first in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me also how to click on the row in order to select it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov just call `click()` on the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Selenium plugin, you can find any element by XPath or CSS expressions.

In order to find the first row using CSS expression, use this string:

```
String cssExpresison = "div[role='row'][row-id='0']";
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssExpression));
we.click();
```

You can use the text written in the first row via XPath:

```
String xPathExpression = "//div[contains(text(), 'Press SPACE to deselect this row')]";
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathExpression));
we.click();
```

If we.click() does Not work, do this:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);            
builder.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```